# Will I lose data on the disk if I add it to a RAID array on a PERC 6/i?

Tags: software-raid, hardware-raid, dell-perc

I am trying to figure out if I can move disks from a Linux software RAID to a hardware RAID on PERC 6/i - and preserve the existing data on the disks. Is it possible to preserve the existing data?

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a hardware based RAID involves an initiliazation process resulting a loss of data. So as far as I understand, a simple migration from Linux software based RAID to hardware based without loosing data will not be possible.

Comment: +1 - Some RAID cards allow the initialization process to be "skipped", but chances are software vs hardware RAID won't be using the same starting sector for "data". The process certainly won't be officially documented anywhere. It's much more worthwhile to simply find a place to store a backup of the data in order to migrate.